# mongoose dynamic define enum values

Tags: enums, mongoose, schema

Is there a way to dynamically define enum values?

```
var mongoose = require('./index'),
TempSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 color: {type: String, enum: ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']}
});
```

in the above 3 strings are defined at design time.
What I would want is to pick up colors from another schema documents and add them to this enum array.
Is it possible?

Comment: You can follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128321/mongoose-dynamic-enum-values