# mongoose dynamic enum values

Tags: node.js, mongoose, enums, mongoose-schema

I have mongoose schema as below.

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin']
  }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I want to set role enum values dynamically from database instead of hard coding, How can I do that?

Comment: Get the values from the database and then initialise your schema?

Comment: what if data in database changes? schema will not be updated until server restarts

Comment: If your data is dynamic then I guess you'll have to add a `pre` hook which queries the enums from database every time before executing your actual queries. To optimise this you could have pub-sub kind of model and just update your enums locally whenever there's a new enum added to the database. This will prevent querying the database every time in the `pre` hook.

Comment: @Vishnu did you get answer for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "validate" on your field. E.G.:

```
//My field is called "status" inside my schema. So "validate" will check if can pass or not.
status: { type: String, default: 'Abierta', validate: (v) => {
    return customEnum(v, 'Status');
}},
```

And this is my "customEnum" module

```
// This is the collection where I store the data. I don't want to use only, status, so
// I made it dynamic, to choose what I want to retrieve.
const SingleValue = require('../models/SingleValue');

module.exports = async (v, type) => {
    return !!await SingleValue.findOne({ typeOf: type, deleted: false, value: v });
}
```

Totally working, I'm using it.